# Symfony2 host matched route matches other routes too

Tags: php, symfony

Here is my routing.yml file

```
admin:
    path: /
    host:     "admin.devhostname.com"
    defaults:
        _controller: AdminBundle:Default:index

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Everything works fine, except `admin.devhostname.com/contact_us` matches my `app` routing for `contact_us`. Because `app:` routing catches `ANY` host config. To get the result I want I need to add `host:` to every other route config. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: try with `prefix: /` instead of `path: /` in the admin routing section. Otherwise you need to declare the `admin_about_us` route

Comment: I've tried that, it's the same, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solution I figured out. So far is the best way.

I moved all site related routes in another file routing_site.yml and then included that routing with `host`.

```
admin:
    path: /
    host:     "admin.%domain%"
    defaults:
        _controller: AdminBundle:Default:index

app:
    resource: routing_site.yml
    host: "%domain%"
```